# Finding the set of all triangles satisfying the given condition

Tags: geometry, triangles

Let $S$ be the set of all triangles $ABC$ for which

$ 5\left( \dfrac{1}{AP} + \dfrac{1}{BQ} + \dfrac{1}{CR} \right) - \dfrac{3}{\min\{ AP, BQ, CR \}} = \dfrac{6}{r},$
where $r$ is the inradius and $P, Q, R$ are the points of tangency of the incircle with sides $AB, BC, CA,$ respectively. How do I Prove that all triangles in $S$ are isosceles and similar to one another.

After taking $s-a=x$, $s-b=y$, $s-c=z$ and assuming WLWOG that  $x \le y \le z$ after much of grueling work I got an equation

$0 = 4y^2z^2 + 25x^2y^2 + 25x^2z^2 - 16xy^2z - 16xyz^2 + 14x^2yz$

How do I solve this equation to get the required result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question you wrote is wrong, it should be $$5\left( \dfrac{1}{AP} + \dfrac{1}{BQ} + \dfrac{1}{CR} \right) - \dfrac{3}{\min\{ AP, BQ, CR \}} = \dfrac{6}{r},\\ and\ not\ \left( \dfrac{1}{AP} + \dfrac{1}{BQ} + \dfrac{1}{CR} \right) - \dfrac{3}{\min\{ AP, BQ, CR \}} = \dfrac{6}{r},                      $$
[This is your answer](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=AUb3thdTTq4C&pg=PA155&lpg=PA155&dq=(1/AP%2B1/BQ%2B1/CR)%E2%88%923/min%7BAP,BQ,CR%7D%3D6/r&source=bl&ots=ffMbQv2I2j&sig=ZcT4_Kw6YHYoh50NMr16Cx0EiJA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwik2vrJx6jdAhUHLI8KHbnlCCQQ6AEwAHoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=(1%2FAP%2B1%2FBQ%2B1%2FCR)%E2%88%923%2Fmin%7BAP%2CBQ%2CCR%7D%3D6%2Fr&f=false/%22answer%22)

I didn't write the answer cause it would take much time , sorry for that.

Comment: Can you please provide the full solution as google books is not allowing me to view the complete solution